# An epitome—grammatically correct?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, grammaticality, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

Can you say "an epitome of" grammatically, or is "the epitome of" the only proper phrasing?

Answer (score 5):

Grammatically there is nothing wrong with saying "an epitome". However there are logical issues with it.

"epitome" is defined as

> A person or thing that is a **perfect** example of a particular quality or type.

Most people would consider that only one thing can be a *perfect* example of anything, since unless two things are identical one must be a better example, and the other is not *perfect*.

You could theoretically say that one of several absolutely identical things is "an epitome" of something.

Comment: Would we expect the dictionary to say "**the** perfect example" in that case?

Answer (score 5):

The Ngram chart for the frequency of "an epitome of" (blue line) versus the frequency of occurrence of "the epitome of" (blue line) in published works included in the Google Books database shows a striking reversal of fortune over the 140 years from 1880 to 2019:

[image]

The shift in relative popularity of the two phrases may not be as simple as it looks in the Ngram chart, however. One crucial complication is that *epitome* has three meanings, and one of those meanings is very different from the other two. Here is the entry for epitome in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **epitome** *n* (1520) **1  a :** a summary of a written work **b :** a brief presentation or statement of something **2 :** a typical or ideal example : EMBODIMENT {the British monarchy is the *epitome* of tradition —Richard Joseph} **3 :** brief or miniature form — usu. used with *in*

However inclined one might be to use *the*, rather than *a*, with *epitome* in sense 2 of the word, no such inclination attaches to senses 1a and 1b. (Sense 3 falls outside my inquiry because, according to the *Eleventh Collegiate*, it tends to take the form "the/a epitome in." If the dominant sense in which *epitome* was used in the period 1750–1920 was "a summary of a written work" or "a brief presentation of something," but the dominant sense of the word after 1940 was "embodiment," it would not be surprising to see the lines for "an epitome of" and "the epitome of" cross at about the year 1940, as they do in the Ngram chart.

In this regard, it seems worthwhile to note the strong preference in English for "the embodiment of" (red line) over "an embodiment of" (blue line), from about 1840 onward:

[image]

When did the "embodiment" sense of *epitome* emerge in English? The shifting and expanding definitions in Merriam-Webster's entries for *epitome* offer some insight into this question. From *Webster's Collegiate Dictionary*, first edition (1898):

> **Epitome**, *n.* A brief summary ; an abridgement ; a condensation ; synopsis.

The entry for *epitome* in the second edition of *Webster's Collegiate* (1910) is unchanged from the one in the first edition. From *Webster's Collegiate Dictionary*, third edition (1916):

> **epitome**, *n.* **1.** A brief statement of the contents of a topic or a work; an abstract. **2.** A compact representation of anything.

The entry for *epitome* in the fourth edition of *Webster's Collegiate* (1949) is unchanged from the one in the third edition. From *Webster's Collegiate Dictionary*, fifth edition (1936):

> **epitome** *n.* **1.** A brief statement of the contents of a topic or a work; abstract. **2.** A part which represents typically a whole.

The entry for *epitome* in the sixth edition of *Webster's Collegiate* (1949) is unchanged from the one in the fifth edition. From *Webster's Seventh New Collegiate Dictionary* (1963):

> **epitome** *n* **1 a :** a summary of a written work **b :** a brief presentation or statement of something **2 :** a typical representation or ideal expression : EMBODIMENT **3 :** brief or miniature form

Evidently, at some point between 1949 and 1963, popular use of *epitome* in the sense of "embodiment" became so substantial that Merriam-Webster decided to add that meaning in its dictionary entry for the term. Obviously this did not mean that the earlier meanings vanished from usage, but it does mark the dictionary's recognition of the rising popularity of the relatively new meaning.

Since the Ngram chart shows the frequency of "an epitome of" dropping rather sharply for at least four decades before the frequency of "the epitome of" begins to rise appreciably, it seems quite possible that *epitome* in its "abstract or synopsis" sense was fading in popularity independently of the emergence of the "embodiment" sense of *epitome*. On the other hand, the diminishing use of *epitome* in its earlier senses may have provided an opening for the new meaning to assert itself with less ambiguity—and of course, speakers' and writers' tendency to attach "the" rather than "a" to *epitome* when using it in this newer sense would have helped reinforce its distinctness from the earlier senses of the word.

---

The OP asks whether one can properly say "an epitome of" when the sense of *epitome* is "embodiment," or whether the only proper phrasing in such situations is "the epitome of." A look at some recent published works indicates that both the indefinite article and the definite article are legitimate options. Consider, for instance, Ansbert Ngurumo, [*John Magufuli: An Epitome of Cowardice*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZGSdDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22an+epitome+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwij1Pul373tAhXuGDQIHWSfABoQ6AEwAHoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22an%20epitome%20of%22&f=false) (2019) or G. Venkataramana Reddy, [*Alayam the Hindu Temple: An Epitome of Hindu Culture*](https://books.google.com/books?id=YCJ3DAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22an+epitome+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwij1Pul373tAhXuGDQIHWSfABoQ6AEwAXoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22an%20epitome%20of%22&f=false) (2016) or this excerpt from I.M. Ezergallis, [*Male and Female: An Approach to Thomas Mann’s Dialectic*](https://books.google.com/books?id=fDeSBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA126&dq=%22an+epitome+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_092-4b3tAhWhJjQIHTHLCuo4KBDoATAEegQIBhAC#v=onepage&q=%22an%20epitome%20of%22&f=false) (2012):

> They [a twin brother and twin sister] are aware of being a pair from birth. Identical, differing only in Wiligis' being **an epitome of** physical manhood and possessing the psychological attributes that go with it, and Sibylla being a comparably perfect incarnation of femininity, they are constantly together as children and adolescents.

Or this excerpt from Dorothea Tanning, [*Between Lives: An Artist and Her World*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Bt2OaoceFBsC&pg=PT232&dq=%22an+epitome+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwisp9Xx4r3tAhWioFsKHcLrCxM4MhDoATAIegQIBRAC#v=onepage&q=%22an%20epitome%20of%22&f=false) (2011):

> In August 1949 we, too, are there with him. **An epitome of** desuetude, the café is deserted except for the surrealists. It is a dim dark-wood-and-mirror kind of place indistinguishable from thousands of other cafés across the city. There sit the surrealists, votaries all, typecast around the table.

In all of these instances, *epitome* means "embodiment," not "summary" or "synopsis" or "brief statement." It thus appears that something can legitimately be "an epitome of" something else or "the epitome of" something else, depending on the speaker's or author's intention and preference.

Comment: Please could you give a *plain text* summary of whatever conclusions you deduce from your NGram searches? // There are quotes from several Merriam-Webster dictionaries. These are American, and this is a confounding factor because it fails to distinguish Americanisms from senses in which "epitome" is used throughout the English-speaking world. How does e.g. the OED's definition compare?

Comment: @RosieF: I tracked the evolution in reported meanings of _epitome_ in Merriam-Webster's dictionaries because MW issued eleven editions of its Collegiate Dictionary series from 1898 to 2003—and I have all of them—which makes it relatively easy to identify (roughly) when the dictionary's staff felt that a new meaning had enough currency and staying power to merit inclusion in the dictionary. By checking the eleven editions of the Collegiate Dictionary, I was able to identify  approximately when _epitome_ in the sense of "embodiment" crossed that threshold in the opinion of Merriam-Webster. ...

Comment: ... You are undoubtedly correct that judgments made about the meaning of _epitome_ in the offices of Merriam-Webster are skewed by the staff's U.S.-centric orientation; unfortunately, I am not in a position to track when _epitome in the sense of "embodiment" became widely recognized in the UK (or elsewhere in the English-speaking world. A review of the smattering of British dictionaries that I have on hand suggests that this meaning change emerged in the UK in the second half of the twentieth century, roughly contemporaneously with its emergence in the US. ...

Comment: ... The evidence supporting this conclusion starts with the entry for _epitome_ in the full-length OED of 1971, which offers these definitions of the word: "1.  brief statement of the chief points in a literary work; an abridgement, abstract. ... b. A summary or condensed account of anything; a compendium of a subject. ... 2. _trans[ferred sense]_ Something that forms a condensed record or representation 'in miniature'. b. In depreciatory sense: Something that is reduced to to insignificant dimensions. _Obs[olete]_. 3. _In epitome_: a. in the form of a summary; b. in a diminutive form." ...

Comment: ...Although the "condensed record or representation 'in miniature'" sense of the word has some kinship to the "embodiment" sense of the word that is of particular interest to me, I think it is quite significant that four of the cited examples refer to "an [not the] epitome" and the only exception—from 1628—clearly intends "epitome" in the sense of "miniature version of," not "embodiment of": "Pauls Walke is the Lands Epitome, or you may call it the lesser Ile of Great Brittaine." ...

Comment: ... Jumping now to _The Concise OED_, revised tenth edition (2001), we get this entry for epitome_:  "**epitome** _n._ **1** (**the epitome of**) a person or thing that is a perfect example of a quality or type **2** a summary of a written work." So from 1971 to 2001, the OED went from having no definition of the "embodiment" sense of _epitome_ to presenting it as the primary meaning—and specifically associating it with the phrase "the epitome of," firmly attaching the definite article with this sense of the word. ...

Comment: ... So when did this change occur in UK English? I don't have the necessary series of Compact OED's to offer an informed opinion on that point. However, I do have a 1987 edition of another British dictionary—_Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English_, new edition—that provides evidence that the "embodiment" sense of _epitome_ was thoroughly established by 1987. ...

Comment: ... Here is the Longman entry for the word: "**epitome** a thing or person  that shows the stated quality or set of qualities to a very great degree; typical example: _ His behavior was the epitome of bad manners_." Here, the older sense of "a summary or condensed account" is nowhere to be found, and the sense of "a representation in miniature" has evolved into "a typical example"—and, more significantly, the normal form of the expression has shifted from "an epitome" to "the epitome."